# Mock interface implementation using Moq in C#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, moq, xamarin.uitest

I am trying to write Xamarin.Forms UI tests using Moq to mock my authentication interface: [previous question][1]. I have refactored my application so that my `SignIn(string username, string password)` method is inside a class that implements the `IAuthService`. I am now having issues with mocking the `IAuthService` to essentially 'replace' the actual sign in verification that occurs when clicking the `Sign In` button. In my `CloudAuthService` class (which implements `IAuthService`), I am authenticating to Amazon Cognito, but I want to mock this result within the UI test so it is not calling the cloud service.

**EDIT:** after many suggestions, I have decided to include my current implementation below. This still doesn't appear to fully work despite the
output from `Console.WriteLine(App.AuthApi.IsMockService());` within the `BeforeEachTest()` method results in `true` (as expected).
However, running the same thing within the `App()` constructor method results in `false`. So it doesn't appear to be running before the app actually starts, is there a way to have UITest code that runs before the app initializes?

**LoginPage**

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public sealed partial class LoginPage
{
    private readonly IBiometricAuthentication _bioInterface;

    private static readonly Lazy<LoginPage>
        Lazy =
            new Lazy<LoginPage>
                (() => new LoginPage(App.AuthApi));

    public static LoginPage Instance => Lazy.Value;

    private string _username;

    private string _password;

    private LoginPageViewModel _viewModel;

    private IAuthService _authService;

    public LoginPage(IAuthService authService)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _authService = authService;

        _viewModel = new LoginPageViewModel();

        BindingContext = _viewModel;
    }

    private void LoginButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
          _username = UsernameEntry.Text;
          _password = PasswordEntry.Text;
          LoginToApplication();
    }

    public async void LoginToApplication()
    {
          AuthenticationContext context = await _authService.SignIn(_username, _password);
    }
}
```

**App Class**

```
public partial class App
{
    public static IAuthService AuthApi { get; set; } = new AWSCognito()
    public App()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(AuthApi.IsMockService())
        // AuthApi = new AWSCognito(); // AWSCognito implements IAuthService
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage(AuthApi));
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
class LoginPageTest
{
    IApp app;
    readonly Platform platform;

    public LoginPageTest(Platform platform)
    {
        this.platform = platform;
    }

    [SetUp]
    public void BeforeEachTest()
    {

        var mocker = new Mock<IAuthService>();

        var response = new AuthenticationContext(CognitoResult.Ok)
        {
            IdToken = "SUCCESS_TOKEN"
        };
        mocker.Setup(x => x.SignIn(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(() => new MockAuthService().SignIn("a", "a"));
        mocker.Setup(x => x.IsMockService()).Returns(() => new MockAuthService().IsMockService());
        App.AuthApi = mocker.Object;
        Console.WriteLine(App.AuthApi.IsMockService());

        app = AppInitializer.StartApp(platform);
    }


    [Test]
    public void ClickingLoginWithUsernameAndPasswordStartsLoading()
    {
        app.WaitForElement(c => c.Marked("Welcome"));
        app.EnterText(c => c.Marked("Username"), new string('a', 1));
        app.EnterText(c => c.Marked("Password"), new string('a', 1));

        app.Tap("Login");

        bool state = app.Query(c => c.Class("ProgressBar")).FirstOrDefault().Enabled;

        Assert.IsTrue(state);
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case, I am just testing that the application displays a loading bar after clicking the Login button. I am trying to mock the `IAuthService` so that the app doesn't call the Amazon Cognito service. I'll update the question with the full test implementation.

Comment: You aren't using the mock. This makes it irrelevant. In order to make your code testable, `app` has to acquire its `_authService` member via a mechanism that allows it to be swapped out.

Comment: @AluanHaddad that makes sense. So if I construct the `LoginPage` so that it gets passed the `IAuthService` instance in some form, then I should theoretically be able to swap out this service with the mocked service?

Comment: @itcoder yes. Exactly. It's best to use constructor parameters for dependencies, but a mutable property can be a last resort. See [Xamarin Forms: Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/dependency-injection) for an example of using DI in this kind of app.

Comment: @itcoder that injection would need to happen earlier than when you try to set that global  property. The instance would have already been created by then.

Comment: I don't know what's idiomatic in Xamarin Forms, but that use of the singleton pattern seem rather awkward.

Comment: @Nkosi I'm kind of confused on how I could inject that property any earlier. Isn't the `public App()` method the first thing to run? Or do you mean inject it earlier in terms of in the test?

Comment: Please note that to be considered on-topic for SO the question must include code inline (as @Nkosi pointed out). That is an edit that **only author of the code** can perform because of licensing restrictions - posting code on SO requires at least [CC BY-SA 4](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) license and thus can't be done by non-author for most of the cases. Consider to [edit] the question to avoid further downvotes/close votes.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be that you've injected the mock *after* you run through the test. This means when it's executing it's using the original AuthService. If we rearrange the code to move the injection before anything gets executed we should see the result we expect:

```cs
    // let's bring this mock injection up here

    var mocker = new Mock<IAuthService>();

    mocker.Setup(x => x.SignIn(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(response)).Verifiable();
    App.AuthApi = mocker.Object;

    // now we try to login, which should call the mock methods of the auth service
    app.WaitForElement(c => c.Marked("Welcome to Manuly!"));
    app.EnterText(c => c.Marked("Username"), new string('a', 1));
    app.EnterText(c => c.Marked("Password"), new string('a', 1));

    app.Tap("Login");
    var response = new AuthenticationContext(CognitoResult.Ok)
    {
        IdToken = "SUCCESS_TOKEN",

    };


    bool state = app.Query(c => c.Class("ProgressBar")).FirstOrDefault().Enabled;

    Assert.IsTrue(state);
```

Now try executing it, and it should do as you desire.

EDIT:
As pointed out in the comments by Nkosi the static Auth service is set in the constructor preventing this.

SO this will need to be changed too:

```cs
public partial class App
{
    public static IAuthService AuthApi { get; set; } =new AWSCognito(); // assign it here statically
    public App()
    {
            // AuthApi = new AWSCognito(); <-- remove this
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage(AuthApi));
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, yeah that makes sense. It still doesn't seem to be replacing the original even in this case, which is quite strange. It may be to do with me using the Singleton pattern on the `LoginPage`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Ah yes, just seen that

Comment: Using static initialization is suboptimal at best. It makes the tests brittle and the injection through a mutable static property for just that one service fails to generalize.

Comment: Agreed, this is very ugly. I would highly recommend a static singleton IoC container (eg. TinyIoC) that can be set up with mock dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. For some reason the above implementation still doesn't work and the original AuthService is still being called. I'll have a look into TinyIoC.

Comment: I thought that setting the mock before the `app = AppInitializer.StartApp(platform)` would work, but this also doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Update: updated original question with current (not working) implementation.